# Never switch desktops when using Task View and opening new app instance

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, task-view

On Windows 10, I am seeing odd issue when using the Task view. Let's take Atom editor as an example. When I have it open on desktop X and switch to desktop Y, clicking on its icon opens up new window. So far so good.

However, when there is already another Atom instance with the same file / workspace, it switches me over instead. I do not want that - I want to make sure that opening an app in a new Task View never switches to existing one.

Is there a setting that can be tweaked to achieve this? Confirmed and tested the behaviour in the aforementioned Atom text editor, as well as the built-in file manager.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set this behaviour in Windows. It's the app, who is focusing itself rather than opening new instance.

Maybe there's a setting for that, that is allowing only one instance in the Atom editor...

Comment: if it's app-specific - is there a place to set this for Windows built-in apps, such as the Explorer?

Comment: Maybe there's a registry key for that..